# Spatial data queries in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, gis, geospatial

Ive got 2 tables:

```
States
Roads
```

Each of them contains geometry column.

How can I write a query to show all roads that crosses state x ? It would be something with `stintersects` but I don't know how to:

```
geom.StIntersects(any object from states)
```

Thank You for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Roads
WHERE Roads.geo.STIntersects(
    (SELECT geo FROM States WHERE Name = 'x')
) = 1
```

Comment: That checks all roads against just one state?

Comment: That seems to have been the request: "How can I write a query to show all roads that crosses state x ?"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Select
  *
From
  Roads
Inner join
  States
    On roads.geomField.stintersects(states.geomField)
```